# What is the best procedure to check an array is empty or not in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using like to check if array is not empty

```
if(array != null){
  //code 
}
```

I also found like that

```
if(Array.isArray(array)){
//code
}
```

and

```
if(array.length){
//code
}
```

Which one is better to use above three ?

Comment: I would say `array.length === 0` or `typeof image_array !== 'undefined' && image_array.length > 0` but that is just me

Comment: Here I do not want to check array is empty or not . I want to know which is better. @Robert,@Milan

Comment: please add what array could be, before checking. the second does only check if `array` is an array and not if there a any items in the array.

Answer (score 27):

I suggest to use [`Array.isArray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) and the [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property of the [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

```
if (Array.isArray(array) && array.length) {
    // code
}
```

because it checks if `array` is an array and if the length has a truthy value.

---

Comparing your attempts:

1. **Truthy check**

   ```
   if (array != null) { // which is basically the same as if (array) {
       //code 
   }
   ```

   This is `true` for all truthy values, like `1`, `'a'`, `{}`. This result is not wanted.
2. **Array check**

   ```
   if (Array.isArray(array)) {
       // code
   }
   ```

   This checks only if `array` is an array, but not the length of it. Empty arrays returns `true`, which is not wanted.
3. **Length check**

   ```
   if (array.length) {
       // code
   }
   ```

   This works only for objects which may have a property of length, which have a truthy value.

   While this comes close to the wanted result, it might be wrong, for example with objects like

   ```
   { length: 'foo' }
   ```

   or with [array-like objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#Working_with_array-like_objects).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to know if an Object is an Array, then `Array.isArray()` will do.

If you want to know if an Array has items, than `array.length !== 0` will do.

If you want to know if a variable is not null than `array !== null` will do.

Comment: since the length can never be less than 0, you can just write if(array.length) - you don't need to compare against 0

Answer (score 2):

I am use to `array.length`
To check if array is not empty, use `if( array.length > 0) {}`

Answer (score 2):

It's better to check the length of the array but there is one issue in it. Consider if someone entered an undefined value in the array then the array will be empty but still have the length greater than 0.

```
for(var i=0,i<array.length;i++){
 if(typeof(array[i]) !== 'undefined'){

 };
};
```

Comment: That helped me as well!

Answer (score 1):

```
var isEmptyArray = function(arr) {
    return (arr || []).length === 0;
}

var arr1 = [1, 2, 3];
var arr2 = [];
var arr3 = undefined;

console.log(isEmptyArray(arr1));  // false
console.log(isEmptyArray(arr2));  // true
console.log(isEmptyArray(arr3));  // true
```

Answer (score 1):

the best solution is

```
if (array.length>0){
....
}
```

but this sentence have a problem if you plan in deleting indexes from the array, since you can have an array like this [undefined,undefined,undefined], whos length is 3 but is technically empty.

```
var a = [1,2,3];
delete a[0];
delete a[1];
delete a[2];
a.length > 0 /// true
a /// [undefined x 3]
```

Take this in consideration to make the exact sentence